# vlookup column value based on selectizeinput value rshiny

Tags: r, filter, shiny, subset, vlookup

Could someone please assist me with the below problem. I started using R shiny recently so I'm terrible at it.

I'm trying to return a value in a different column based on the choice selected in selectizeinput. e.g. I have 2 tables that look like this:

Table A

```
ID  Car
1   Volvo
2   Almera
3   Toyota
4   Ranger
```

Table B

```
ID  Date
1   09-Sep-09
2   23-Oct-02
3   06-Dec-95
4   18-Jan-89
```

in my selectizeinput my choices are the IDs. I want a function which will return the Date and Car value depending on the ID selected in the dropdown.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated
Regards,
Katy

Comment: Hi KatyLearnR and welcome to SO ! Could you share the bit of code you want to improve ? Here is the link to find all the ways to share [a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm currently creating a dataframe using the below code:

  df$ID <- as.character(selectizeInput("id","",choices = unique(Table_A$ID)))

and I want to create a second column in the dataframe which will return the date and car based on the value selected in the dropdown created by the above code. 

I've tried using :
  df2$Date= reactive({Table_B$Date %>% dplyr::filter(Table_B$ID==input$policynumber)})

but i get an error saying "closure is not subsettable" and "no matching records found" in the webapp table

Comment: Please update you question with your code so that anybody can jump in to help. :) It feels like you are mixing `ui` and `server` side : the 2 different parts of a shiny app. It would save you some times to do the [rstudio-tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) (which is quite nice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is minimal example with the data provided and the example sample code from [selectInput help page](https://rdrr.io/cran/shiny/man/selectInput.html). You should first join the data, test how to fiter it then write the app :

```r
table_cars <- read.table(text = "
ID  Car
1   Volvo
2   Almera
3   Toyota
4   Ranger", header = TRUE)

table_date <- read.table(text = "ID  Date
1   09-Sep-09
2   23-Oct-02
3   06-Dec-95
4   18-Jan-89", header = TRUE)

table_join <- merge(table_cars, table_date, by="ID")

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                table_join$ID),
    tableOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderTable({
      table_join[table_join$ID %in% input$variable, ]
    }, rownames = FALSE)
  }
)
```